# specifying JSON in a POST to get information from a REST server

Tags: json, web-services, rest

I am asking about what the accepted best practices are in retrieving information from a REST server where the client needs to provide some data.

Usually it is done as CGI parameters... but is it OK to do a POST with a json payload with the info in order to get information?

Comment: Could you provide an example for such a request? What would the parameters be like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Although typically you use a GET to retrieve data in RESTFul services it is not actually specified that it has to be that way.  It is quite acceptable for it do be done by a POST.

See related question  [PUT vs POST in REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest?rq=1)

For it to be RESTful it has to have the following. Uniform Interface, Stateless, Cacheable, Client-Server, Layered System, Code on Demand (optional).   There is no specification anywhere that says you must use a particular HTTP method for a particular function or even HTTP methods at all.

Comment: I disagree. To get a resource, `GET` is to be used.

Comment: Have you got any facts to back up your disagreement?

Comment: "or even HTTP methods at all" That is true. It is also true that, as long as your protocol allows it, you can make a HTTP `DELETE` request with JSON body which the server uses to create a new resource. But doing REST this way would not be what most people expect. Since the OP is asking about HTTP `POST` for making a request that basically has `GET` semantics, it is bad advise to tell him: "You can do whatever the proctol dos not reject since REST is only an architectural style that follows a set of principles." Doing REST in the real world also means: Don't confuse people. You do.